# Component cannot be used as a JSX component. Its return type 'Element[]' is not a valid JSX element

Tags: reactjs, typescript

The following error occurs in the `Todos` component inside the `TodoApp.tsx`:

```
'Todos' cannot be used as a JSX component.
  Its return type 'Element[]' is not a valid JSX element.
    Type 'Element[]' is missing the following properties from type 'Element': type, props, key
```

Corresponding files:

`TodoApp.tsx`

```
function TodoApp() {
  return (
    <Body>
      <AppDiv>
        <Form />
        <Todos />
        <Footer />
      </AppDiv>
    </Body>
  );
}
```

`Todos.tsx`

```
function Todos(): JSX.Element[] {
  const todos = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.todos);
  const footer = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.footer);

  if (footer.hideAll) {
    if (footer.showCompleted) {
      return todos
        .filter((todo) => !todo.completed)
        .map((todo: any) => (
          <>
            <ul>
              <Todo todo={todo} />
            </ul>
          </>
        ));
    }
    return todos.map((todo) => (
      <>
        <div>
          <Todo todo={todo} />
        </div>
      </>
    ));
  }

  return todos.map(() => (
    <>
      <div></div>
    </>
  ));
}
```

`Todo.tsx`

```
type Todo = {
  todo: TodoProps;
};

const Todo = ({ todo }: Todo) : JSX.Element => {
  const [isEditing, edit] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  if (!isEditing) {
    return (
      <TodoDiv>
        <Li
          key={todo.id}
          completed={todo.completed}
          onClick={() => dispatch(completeTodo(todo.id))}
          // style={{
          //   textDecoration: todo.completed ? "line-through" : "none"
          // }}
        >
          {todo.text}
        </Li>
        <TodoBttns>
          <Button edit onClick={() => edit(!isEditing)}>
            <img src={editBttn} alt="Edit Button" />
          </Button>
          <Button delete onClick={() => dispatch(deleteTodo(todo.id))}>
            <img src={deleteBttn} alt="Delete Button" />
          </Button>
        </TodoBttns>
      </TodoDiv>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <FormEdit>
        <InputForm key={todo.id} {...{ todo, edit }} />
      </FormEdit>
    );
  }
};
```

and the `TodoProps` interface is defined as follows

```
interface TodoProps {
  text: string;
  completed: boolean;
  id: string;
}
```

I have tried fixing it by wrapping the map of items with fragments, but the error is still thrown. The only thing that as of now is fixing the issue is declaring at the top of `Todos.tsx` the function as any: `function Todos(): any`

As a side note: I'm using `StyledComponents`, but I don't think the issue is related to the library.

Comment: How about just wrapping it into a fragment https://en.reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html#short-syntax ?

Comment: @Amadare42 already tried this with no results (unless I misinterpreted the use of fragments and I'm doing something wrong?)

Edit: changed the code on my first post to use fragments

Comment: like so: 
`function ToDo(): JSX.Element {
  return <>
    { todos.map(a => <div key={a} />) }
  </>
}
`

Comment: @Amadare42 just tried using fragments like the way you suggested (and in a few other places) but still doesn't work

Comment: In your example you seems to specify that Todo always returns `JSX.Element[]` which isn't true. If you ditch this type, this should be working. Check this example: https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-bird-peqpl?file=/src/App.tsx

Answer (score 202):

A component needs to return a single root element. You can use fragments to package an array of elements as a single element, by using the fragment as that single root element.

So this does nothing:

```
function Todos(): JSX.Element {
  return todos.map(todo => (
    <>
      <li>{todo.task}</li>
    </>
  )
}
```

Because it's now returning an array of `[<><li/></>, <><li/></>, ...]`. That fragment needs to be the single root element.

You need to use the fragment like this:

```
function Todos(): JSX.Element {
  return <>{
    todos.map(todo => <li>{todo.task}</li>)
  }</>
}
```

You nest all returned JSX in one single fragment.

Using that pattern you may end up with somehting like this:

```
function Todos(): JSX.Element {
  const todos = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.todos);
  const footer = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.footer);

  if (footer.hideAll) {
    if (footer.showCompleted) {
      return <>{
        todos
          .filter((todo) => !todo.completed)
          .map((todo: any) => (
            <ul>
              <Todo todo={todo} />
            </ul>
          ))
      }</>
    }
    return <>{
      todos.map((todo) => (
        <div>
          <Todo todo={todo} />
        </div>
      ))
    }</>
  }

  return <>{
    todos.map(() => (
      <div></div>
    ))
  }</>
}

// Works without error
<Todos />
```

Note how each return statement returns just one `JSX.Element`: the fragment.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?jsx=2#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wChTMBXAOw2AmrgBUIATCAZwAoBKALjgApAMoANAHQBRADZIQSavADepOHDQMO8GG05wAvHEockwpLIzQuXLShhIBCCBBjCYdpDwMA+OLfviOuwcPADcquqaWM72UAZGJmYWOlDW-g6IMW4eXvq+6eKYMUhQYeRqwJhwXEUuJeIAFsCsSACC0tJeKmoVVTXFUOIcDRAA7gDCuGCy9qxdET1wRDCUUIwAPN7diz1BnAs7aoXA0rHWe7m+AIR74hrgM0hzB4fiIChg57oCKNQAnpdqi9DnB1pRpN5gSDQSx2HA9volHsAL5wAD0kOhi3WaPBmKxPB4wOROPxamRB2Wqw2W2Bew4bw+X3YgK4UNBrGAADcySD1rCIPDdIiUejedi0ZyecDCQcSRiIhSIlS1qDaYt6YzPrwfEDDuspd4cYaDrLyaTSEq0Wi4AB1aAAaw4pH5ug4GKAA)

Comment: Ok, this solved it. But out of curiosity, why is that with normal React I can return an array and it works just fine, but with TS, I have to specify that it's a single React element?

Comment: Because react treats components differently. Arrays can be children of JSX nodes, but components rendered via `<CamelCasedComponentName/>` must return a single element. React uses the document structure to add stuff to components like state and hook data. Without that single root component, there is no object to put that state on. But when you just render a list, it can rely on the component rendering that to keep state (which internally is the root element of that component).

Comment: @AlexWayne not entirely true.
From the docs:
> A React component can also return an array of elements.

Seems like a TypeScript / types issue:

https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/20356

and 

https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21699

Answer (score 169):

Add the following code

```
"paths": {
   "react": [ "./node_modules/@types/react" ]
 }
```

to `tsconfig.json` file, in compilerOptions

Here is how my code looks like now:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "jsx":"react",
    "strict": true,
    "paths": {
      "react": [ "./node_modules/@types/react" ]
    }
  }
}
```

It is telling the typescript compiler that when it encounters a reference to the "react" module, it should look for the actual implementation in the "./node_modules/@types/react" directory.

Comment: This gets removed from tsconfig.json the moment I run `npm run start-js`?

Comment: This did not work in my case.

Comment: This solves my case where react-dom createRoot(el).render(<App />) throws error: "Argument of type 'Element' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ReactNode'.

Comment: Worked like a charm as ReactDOM.render was failing for this reason, thanks!

Comment: made my day, thanks!

Comment: made my day, thank you!!!

Comment: This worked for me

Comment: This worked like a charm. I still don't know why this works, but I don't care at this point because this solution has resolved hours of anxiety for me 

Answer (score 36):

For a scenario when someone has upgraded to later `React`, e.g., `16` -> `17` it could start happening.

Now, while looking for `@types/react` in your project, you could notice many `npm` packages have `@types/react : "*",`. The solution to get rid off the problem, in that scenario, would be to add into your `package.json`:

```json
"resolutions": {
  "@types/react": "^17.0.38"
}
```

Comment: Just one suggestion. Run `yarn install` or `npm install` after updating `package.json` to see the error gone

Comment: So useful when upgrading from react 16 to 17. Thanks! 
In the end using `"@types/react": "^17.0.38"` instead of `"@types/react": "^17"` fixed it for me. No need to add this extra config with `resolutions`

Answer (score 17):

You need to return a JSX Element, not an array.
Wrapping the whole component is a solution, but you need to do it outside of the map/filter function.

```
Todos.tsx

function Todos(): JSX.Element {
  const todos = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.todos);
  const footer = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.footer);

  if (footer.hideAll) {
    if (footer.showCompleted) {
      return (
        <>
          {todos.filter((todo) => !todo.completed).map((todo: any) => (
            <ul>
              <Todo todo={todo} />
            </ul>
           ));
          }
        </>
    }
    return (
      <>
        {todos.map((todo) => (
          <div>
            <Todo todo={todo} />
          </div>
        ));
        }
      </>
  }

  return (
    <>{todos.map(() => <div />)}</>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 13):

In case anyone is facing issue with React + Typescript stack, try adding below setting in tsconfig.json. It worked for me.

"allowSyntheticDefaultImports" : true

Answer (score 11):

I'm facing the same issue about this error. I add the below code to my **package.json** file.

```
"resolutions": {
  "@types/react": "17.0.2",
  "@types/react-dom": "17.0.2",
},
```

Then, Run `yarn install` on a terminal.

It works for me.

Comment: For the first time, it solved my problem!

Comment: `graphql` seems to be redundant here

Comment: Wow! After spending a full day on this issue, I can't believe it finally worked. Thank you for sharing this!

Comment: You could have put it in "dependencies" or "devDependencies" instead of in "resolutions"

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes this error can occur when you use the `switch case` syntax to render your component.

For example:

```
switch (loading) {
    case "pending":
      return <span>Pending</span>;
    case "succeeded":
      return <span>Succeeded</span>;
    case "failed":
      return <span>Failed</span>;
```

Sometimes your loading status can mistakenly have a value that you didn't specify in the `case`, so your component will return `undefined`. Therefore, you should add a `default` value:

```
default: return <span>¯\_(ツ)_/¯</span>;
```

Comment: This was something I had run into and was only able to find errors for when importing the component elsewhere. Thank you, much appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

In my case, it was a forgotten import. Basically copy-pasted some of my code and forgot to import one of the components and this was the error message I get.

Comment: You should use an IDE for this and many other things. VSCode works great for me.

Comment: I am already using Vscode but sometimes it is not logical enough to detect such mistakes.

Answer (score 4):

There's a possibility that you have installed (and probably failed) a new package, which could also cause this error.

If that's the case (that you have recently installed and failed or cancelled a package), you can delete `node_modules` and run `npm i` or `yarn install` then try again.

Answer (score 4):

You might neeed to add the `@types/react` and `@types/react-dom` to your `package.json`.

Comment: Someone already posted this exact same answer

Answer (score 3):

You need to install types for react `npm install @types/react` or `yarn add @types/react`

Answer (score 2):

Here's another possibility. **TL;DR**: look for `node_modules` folders outside your project root (see `node -e "console.log(global.module.paths)"`) and delete them.

Node searches for packages in `node_modules` folders over several paths, often going from your project root to your system root. See `node -e "console.log(global.module.paths)"` for where it'll look. Let's say you installed, for example, `@types/react@17.0.2` (or whatever version) in your project root – you'll see it your `node_modules` there. But then you (perhaps accidentally, perhaps transitively) also installed `@types/react@18.2.0` in one of those other search paths instead of your project root.

When Node goes searching, it finds both types dependencies: `17.0.2` and `18.2.0`, and when it finds two differing React major versions for types it can cause problems because Typescript types packages have a [bad habit](https://github.com/microsoft/DefinitelyTyped-tools/issues/433) of using `*` dependency ranges and the packaging default is to simply install the latest version. In this example, your React 17 project would fail to compile with weird errors like like `'Todos' cannot be used as a JSX component` because it is being compiled using the React 18 types. See [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/24304) for a painful example of mixed 17 and 18 types. I'm sure there could be conflicts between other versions as well, and also this doesn't just apply to React, it could apply to any library with drastically changing APIs/types and enthusiastic developers.

There are many variations of this example, but the solution is to delete the `node_modules` folders that are outside your project root along the Node search path, and then make sure you actually have the packages you need in the `node_modules` in your project root. This will remove the React types version conflicts and you should compile with just your regular dumb easily-solvable errors instead.

You may have a reason for keeping packages outside your project root, in which case you either know what you're doing or good luck – Typescript packages do not resolve well at all in our current ecosystem. If you have multiple projects with differing React versions, place them in your filesystem so that their Node search paths don't conflict, and make sure you don't have a `node_modules` sitting in your system or user root somewhere where it'd find them.

Comment: This description was useful to fix the root cause issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Another common cause of the "Component cannot be used as a JSX component" error is when we return anything other than a JSX element or null from a component, or forget to return a value.

The App component returns undefined because we have placed our return statement on one line and the JSX code on the next **without using parentheses**.

We aren't allowed to return **undefined** from a component, so the error occurs.

Comment: You need a linter, nextjs has a good one https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/configuring/eslint

Answer (score 1):

```
"paths": {
  "@/*": [
    "./*"
  ],
  "react": [ "./node_modules/@types/react" ]
},
```

add this to your tsconfig.json file, it works

Comment: This is the same as what was suggested in one of the top voted answers

Answer (score 0):

This answer is related to same problem on react-native.
Adding typescript to my newly created react-native app and moving App.js to App.tsx, I met the same error for component named Section. The solution for me was a component type `React.Fc<{...}>`.
This is the problematic Section component after the fix when all errors disappeared and my app started as expected.

```
 import React, { ReactNode } from 'react';
 import {
   SafeAreaView,
   ScrollView,
   StatusBar,
   StyleSheet,
   Text,
   useColorScheme,
   View,
 } from 'react-native';
 
 import {
   Colors,
   DebugInstructions,
   Header,
   LearnMoreLinks,
   ReloadInstructions,
 } from 'react-native/Libraries/NewAppScreen';
 
 const Section: React.FC<{  
  children: ReactNode;   
  title: string; 
}> = ({children, title}) => {
   const isDarkMode = useColorScheme() === 'dark';
   return (
     <View style={styles.sectionContainer}>
       <Text
         style={[
           styles.sectionTitle,
           {
             color: isDarkMode ? Colors.white : Colors.black,
           },
         ]}>
         {title}
       </Text>
       <Text
         style={[
           styles.sectionDescription,
           {
             color: isDarkMode ? Colors.light : Colors.dark,
           },
         ]}>
         {children}
       </Text>
     </View>
   );
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

I followed some of the steps above where I had to declare the types within pacakge.json but that did not work for me.

I had to manually update the `yarn.lock` file to React version 16. It was displaying version 18.x in the lock file.

You may also want to update the resolved url to match but test before doing so.

`version "18.0.28"` to `version "16.14.15"`

```bash
"@types/react@*":
  version "16.14.15" 
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@types/react/-/react-17.0.39.tgz#d0f4cde092502a6db00a1cded6e6bf2abb7633ce"
  integrity sha512-UVavlfAxDd/AgAacMa60Azl7ygyQNRwC/DsHZmKgNvPmRR5p70AJ5Q9EAmL2NWOJmeV+vVUI4IAP7GZrN8h8Ug==
  dependencies:
    "@types/prop-types" "*"
    "@types/scheduler" "*"
    csstype "^3.0.2"
```

Comment: You're not supposed to manually edit yarn lock like that. You should use console commands that will update both `package.json` and `yarn.lock` to the desired version.

Answer (score 0):

You probably shouldn't get this error if you're running on the latest TS version `@types/react`, `@types/react-dom`, etc. Here's a thread for anyone interested in knowing the cause of this issue:

- https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/51328
- https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/42292

I have a unique use-case in which I do not have access to upgrade any packages (working with an online editor). A quick hack is ignoring the warning using the `@ts-expect-error` directive.

For example:

```
import Component from "./Component"

export default function App({children}: {children: React.ReactNode}) {
  return (
   <div className="App">
     {/* @ts-expect-error */}
     <Component />
     {children}
   </div>
 )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just specify the JSX dialect by changing the `jsx` option in `tsconfig.json` to `react-jsx` like so:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions: {
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
  }
}
```

This is an **alternative** answer to Or Nakash's [asnwer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75093164/3593896) above, which suggests adding a path like so:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions: {
    "paths": {
      "react": ["./node_modules/@types/react"]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In my case I forgot to put back ticks after `styled(PreviousStyledElement);`
After I put them the code started to work.

```css
export const MyNewStyledElement = styled(PreviousStyledElement)``;
```

Answer (score -1):

you returned something when your condition is true but you didn't return anything when the condition is not satisfied. This is what the error says exactly.

Answer (score -2):

When you import anything then try to import in Curly Braces.

for example when we import Box in React Component try to write

```
import {Box} from "@mui/material" instead of 
import Box from "@mui/material"
```

Comment: This solve my Problems

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).