# Styled components could not be used as JSX element (React, Typescript)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

My wrapper looks like this.

```
import styled from "styled-components";
import React from "react";

const WrapperDiv = styled.div`
    margin: 20px 0px;
    padding: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    box-shadow: rgba(9, 30, 66, 0.25) 0px 1px 1px, rgba(9, 30, 66, 0.31) 0px 0px 1px 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
`;

export type Props = {
    children: React.ReactNode;
};

const Wrapper = (props: Props) => {
    return <div>
            <WrapperDiv>
                <div style={{ margin: "1em" }}>{props.children}</div>
            </WrapperDiv>
        </div>
};

export default Wrapper;
```

and getting the following error

```
'WrapperDiv' cannot be used as a JSX component.
  Its instance type 'Component<ThemedOuterStyledProps<DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>, any>, any, any>' is not a valid JSX element.
    The types returned by 'render()' are incompatible between these types.
      Type 'React.ReactNode' is not assignable to type 'import("/Users/pmurugesan/work/onboarding/cerulean-tm-public/node_modules/@types/react-select/node_modules/@types/react/index").ReactNode'.
        Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.ts(2786)
```

I could not understand the error message better. Can someone help me with this? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62702903/13405106

Comment: @Usama that's a different issue

Comment: I have a similar issue. It seems to occur because of the @types/react version dependency of your @types/react-select package uses an incompatible version and it clashes with your app dependency.

`yarn why @types/react` will give you some insight. Probably one is 17 and one is 18. I don't yet know a solution yet. I think `yarn set resolution` should be able to solve it but I can't get it to work yet...

Comment: I have the same problem have you figured it out?