# how to solve cannot be used as a JSX component for typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

**Problem**
I getting error for Dialog,DialogContent,DialogContentText,DialogTitle,CropperDemo

> 'Dialog' cannot be used as a JSX component.

**Question**

How to solve this error?

```
import * as React from "react";
import Dialog from "@mui/material/Dialog";
import DialogContent from "@mui/material/DialogContent";
import DialogContentText from "@mui/material/DialogContentText";
import DialogTitle from "@mui/material/DialogTitle";
import CropperDemo from "./cropper";

export default function Popup({ open, image, handleClose, getCroppedFile }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <Dialog
        open={open}
        onClose={handleClose}
        aria-labelledby="alert-dialog-title"
        aria-describedby="alert-dialog-description"
      >
        <DialogTitle id="alert-dialog-title">Crop Image</DialogTitle>
        <DialogContent>
          <DialogContentText id="alert-dialog-description">
            <CropperDemo
              handleClose={handleClose}
              src={image}
              getCroppedFile={getCroppedFile}
            />
          </DialogContentText>
        </DialogContent>
      </Dialog>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Please explain in detail because this is new for me

Comment: Do you have these 2 packages, `@types/react` and `@types/react-dom` installed?

Comment: yes i have those package

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Component cannot be used as a JSX component. Its return type 'Element\[\]' is not a valid JSX element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62702485/component-cannot-be-used-as-a-jsx-component-its-return-type-element-is-not)

Comment: for dialog  Its type '(props: DialogProps) => Element' is not a valid JSX element type.
    Type '(props: DialogProps) => Element' is not assignable to type '(props: any, deprecatedLegacyContext?: any) => ReactNode'.
      Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.
        Property 'children' is missing in type 'Element' but required in type 'ReactPortal'

Comment: for DialogTitle  Its type 'OverridableComponent<DialogTitleTypeMap<{}, "span">>' is not a valid JSX element type.
    Type 'OverridableComponent<DialogTitleTypeMap<{}, "span">>' is not assignable to type '(props: any, deprecatedLegacyContext?: any) => ReactNode'.
      Type 'Element | null' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.
        Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.

Comment: 'DialogContent' cannot be used as a JSX component.
  Its type '(props: DialogContentProps) => Element' is not a valid JSX element type.
    Type '(props: DialogContentProps) => Element' is not assignable to type '(props: any, deprecatedLegacyContext?: any) => ReactNode'.
      Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.

Comment: 'CropperDemo' cannot be used as a JSX component.
  Its type '({ src, getCroppedFile }: { src: any; getCroppedFile: any; }) => Element' is not a valid JSX element type.
    Type '({ src, getCroppedFile }: { src: any; getCroppedFile: any; }) => Element' is not assignable to type '(props: any, deprecatedLegacyContext?: any) => ReactNode'.
      Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.

Comment: Check all of your packages related to React core packages and the `mui` packages are in the latest version.

Comment: thanks its working i update all packages